# Is there any way in jmeter where i can add delay time between half requests in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to send 100 users in 5 seconds and my loop count is 1, but i want to add delay time of 10 seconds after 50 users then remaining 50 users will hit.
Please help me with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [Stepping Thread](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) Group to perform the action required. By Configuring the steps according to your requirement.

Comment: Is this the only feasible solution ? Because for this i have to download plugins for jmeter.

Comment: Synchronizing Timer: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/11/jmeter-synchronizing-timer.html , Can be used to restrict the threads required.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are mutually exclusive, first you're talking about 5 seconds and then you need 10 seconds delay which brings us to at least 15 seconds plus your application response time.

The easiest option would be going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can easily set up whatever workload you want.

Alternatively you can go for the:

- [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler - to introduce the 10-seconds delay
- [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to act as a "rendezvous" point for the virtual users